# .NET Working with Locking and Threads

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking

Work on this small test application to learn threading/locking.  I have the following code, I would think that the line should only write to console once.  However it doesn't seem to be working as expected.  Any thoughts on why?  What I'm trying to do is add this Lot object to a List, then if any other threads try and hit that list, it would block.  Am i completely misusing lock here?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int threadCount = 10;

        //spin up x number of test threads
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[threadCount];
        Work w = new Work();
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            threads[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(w.DoWork));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < threadCount; i++)
        {
            threads[i].Start();
        }

        // don't let the console close
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class Work
{
    List<Lot> lots = new List<Lot>();
    private static readonly object thisLock = new object();

    public void DoWork()
    {
        Lot lot = new Lot() { LotID = 1, LotNumber = "100" };
        LockLot(lot);
    }

    private void LockLot(Lot lot)
    {
        // i would think that "Lot has been added" should only print once?
        lock (thisLock)
        {
            if(!lots.Contains(lot))
            {
                lots.Add(lot);
                Console.WriteLine("Lot has been added");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it should only print once?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lock` statement ensures that two pieces of code will not execute simultaneously.

If two threads enter a `lock` block at once, the seconbd thread will wait until the first one finishes, *then continue and execute the block*.

In your code, `lots.Contains(lot)` is always `false` because the `DoWork` method creates a different `Lot` object in each thread.  Therefore, eah thread adds another `Lot` object after acquiring the lock.

You probably want to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in your `Lot` class and make it compare by value, so that `lots.Contains(lot)` will return `true` for different `Lot` objects with the same values.

Comment: @Erup: Actually, `List<T>.Contains` doesn't use `GetHashCode`.  However, it should still be (correctly) overridden.

Answer (score 2):

`lock` is essentially a critical section, and will only lock the object while the code within is executed. As soon as the code exists the `lock` block, the object will be unlocked. So... it makes sense that each thread would (eventually) print to console.

You are creating a new `Lot` object on each thread, so if you have not defined your own Equals method for the object it makes sense that `lots.Contains(lot)` will always return false.

Answer (score 1):

You need the lock statement to protect shared data, variables that are read *and* written by more than one thread at the same time.  The "lot" variable doesn't qualify that requirement, every thread creates its own instance of a Lot object.  And the reference is stored in a local variable ("lot"), every thread has its own local variables.

The lots field *does* fit the requirement.  There is only one instance of it, because there is only one instance of the Work class, all threads access it.  *And* threads both read and write to the list, respectively through the Contains method and the Add method.  Your lock statement prevents a thread from accessing the list at the same time and is correct, Contains can never run at the same time as Add.

You are 95% there, you just missed that each thread has a unique "lot" object.  One that cannot have been added to the list before.  Every single thread will therefore get a false return from Contains.

If you want the Lot class to have identity, based on the LotID and LotNumber property values instead of just the object instance, then you'll need to give it identity by overriding the Equals() and GetHashCode() method.  Check your favorite C# programming book, they all mention this.  It doesn't otherwise have anything to do with threading.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you only expect it to run once?  You call DoWork in 10 different threads, each one creates its own "new Lot()" object.  Were you expecting value comparison of Lot objects?  Did you override Equals() and implement IEquatable?

Comment: So many questions... the author is asking for an answer from you!

Comment: The author said he's trying to learn about threading.  Asking leading questions is a useful teaching technique.

Comment: Yes, when the leading questions are leading toward an answer, they are useful.